# How do I get rid of the gap on the right hand side of a maximised terminal when running Vim?

Tags: gnome-terminal, vim, konsole, neovim

On multiple versions of Ubuntu, Vim and Neovim display a horrible gap on the right hand side of the terminal when it is maximised.

This is Gnome terminal:

[image]

And this is Konsole:

[image]

This does not happen when the terminal is not maximised because it only then only expands to the right by what apears to be full character pixel widths in the case of Gnome terminal at least. This issue also only occurs with Vim colour schemes which paint the background a different colour to the terminal background, such as in the gnome picture above, *dw_green*, or for Konsole, *aqua*.

Is there any way to alter Vim/Neovim behaviour, to force them to paint right to the edge even when there isn't a full character's space there?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can refer this link: https://thomashunter.name/posts/2019-01-20-removing-gvim-border

> This is because the width and height of the screen is not perfectly divisible by the width and height of a character.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.